# Javascript - Getting document width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get the document's width with javascript (jQuery available), which I could achieve simply with `document.width`. The problem comes up when the contents are positioned with a negative value, because `document.width` will retrieve the width less that value (you can see this behavior in http://jsfiddle.net/McgzK/1/). So, is there a way I can get the document's width straight forward, or should I do something like `document.width - parseInt($(container).css('left'))`?

Comment: What about `$(document.body​).width()` ?

Comment: I won't work (you can try it in the fiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to get that width. This width does not make any sense. `document.width` is the value of documents width. If you put something outside document layout its not included in documents width as **its not in the document**. So for your *Total width* you have to add that portion.

Use the [scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth) property of your element and add absolute `left` value of css position.

See http://jsfiddle.net/McgzK/11/

Note:

1. if you want the width of content use `scrollWidth` property.
2. If you want to get the width of the *element*  use `offsetWidth`.

Comment: use the property against your element. Not `document`. If You want to use something like docuemnt. Use `document.body`. See I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but in http://jsfiddle.net/McgzK/3/ I'm using `document.body` (and not `document`), and still does not work. In the fiddle you provided you are getting just the width of the visible part of the element

Comment: What you actually want?? content-width or width of invisible part?

Comment: The whole document width, what is seen and what is not. That is why I tried to use `document.width`, which will work fine as long as the contents are not positioned with a negative `left`. So I just wanted to know if there's a straight forward way to get that value, instead of doing some sums.

Comment: add the css left value with scrollwidth!

Comment: Did you actually read the question or looked at the code of my fiddle? Read it again, please, till the end.

Comment: document.width is the value of documents width. If you put something outside document layout its not included in documents width as its not in the document. So for your `total_width` you have to add that portion.

Comment: Also you might want to check this update and try to match which width you want! http://jsfiddle.net/McgzK/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your body width to 100% in your CSS, then use jQuery to get the width of the body rather than the document.